# Alexa unable to vocalize certain sentences

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am building a new skill.  I have encountered a problem where Alexa cannot vocalize certain sentences.  Here is an example sentence, taken from a news article about the recent Turkish earthquake:
"Turkish authorities consider the Syrian Democratic Forces to be a terrorist group, along with the Kurdistan Workers' Party, or PKK, a Turkey-based Kurdish separatist group."
To replicate the problem:
-Go into the amazon developer console
-Enter any skill under development
-Click the Test tab
--Click on Voice and Tone to simulate the system response
-Paste the sentence between the   tags
-Click the play button

You will hear the two-tone beep signalling failure.

Interestingly, if you remove the word "Kurdistan" from the sentence alexa can read it without problem.  Alexa can also vocalize "Kurdistan" on its own, but it seems that in the combination of the above sentence something is wrong.  Is this an issue of censorship, where alexa thinks the sentence is too controversial?

I would like to find some work-arounds, as I will be serving news content from many sources and don't know in advance if the wording will trip the system up.

I have modified the sentence, both in my skill and in the test tab, to try and make it work.

I have attempted to resolve this with the alexa development tech support, but seem to be getting the run-around.  They have closed the case without followin my explicit instructions on how to replicate the problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please consult the policy requirements to understand more about what type of content are allowed in the Alexa skill.

https://developer.amazon.com/pt-BR/docs/alexa/custom-skills/policy-requirements-for-an-alexa-skill.html

If after checking the requirements you are still having questions, you can reach reach out to the Alexa Developer Support via this link: https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/contact-us